# TarsosDSP with android

Tags: java, android, audio, tarsosdsp

I am trying to use TarsosDSP library with android, but it needs to use the javax.sound.sampled library which is not available on android as far as I'm aware.

is there any way to include the javax.sound.sampled package in android?

I found a library at - https://github.com/jld/linaro-android-gcc/tree/master/gcc-4.7/libjava/javax/sound/sampled, but this contains only .h files which i know are header files. is there a way of compiling this package into a jar which i can then use with android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use TarsosDSP within an Android application you don't really need the `javax.sound.*` packages. What is needed however, is a bridge between incoming audio and the TarsosDSP API. The incoming audio can be from a mirophone or an audio file. In Android this bridge is provided by the `android.media` packages.

In practice this means you need to make a fork of TarsosDSP and leave out all references to `javax.sound.*`. Luckily, someone already prepared this for you: https://github.com/srubin/TarsosDSP/releases/tag/TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD

Regards,

Joren

Comment: And now the TarsosDSP package has Android support out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, since some time TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD is not needed anymore, as described on official site:

> the fork of TarsosDSP kindly provided by GitHub user srubin, created
>   for a programming assignment at UC Berkley, is not needed any more.

See [official documentation](http://0110.be/posts/TarsosDSP_on_Android_-_Audio_Processing_in_Java_on_Android).