# TarsosDSP with Android - no relevant source code

Tags: android, mp3, weka

I follow up on this article: [TarsosDSP with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914048/tarsosdsp-with-android)

I am trying to implement an android application that reads mp3 files and processes them using WEKA.
The TarsosDSP seems to be a good step in the right direction, especially since the Berkley guys seems to have implemented a fork with android.
When I tried downloading their source code here: [TarsosDSPAndroid Source Code](https://github.com/srubin/TarsosDSP/releases/tag/TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD)
I still found a lot of references to javax.sound, which is kind of counter-productive.

So is something mixed up with their uploaded source code or am I looking in the wrong place?

Perhaps some background to what I am trying to accomplish overall:
I am writing an Android App that will read the entire mp3 library, and using WEKA and pre-loaded test-groups will classify each song to appropriate genre.
The part of reading the mp3 library is all done and so is the classification using WEKA, now I am stuck in joining them up - What seemed to be working fine using jAudio in a java project doesn't work for android because of the dependency in javax.sound, so I am trying to bypass that using a different library that works for android.

Thanks in advance!
-Alex

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0 of TarsosDSP supports Android out of the box. There are no more dependencies on `javax.sound.*`. This makes it a lot more easy to work with on Android. There is even an [TarsosDSP Android jar file](http://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-latest/TarsosDSP-Android-latest-bin.jar) that can be included in your project directly.